# Using google places API in node.js server enviroment

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my first node.js application where I will be using javascript in the server, previously I used google places API javascripe in the client, like this:

```
async codeAddressFromList(address)
    {
        const self = this;
        this.address = address;
    
        return self.geocoderService.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status == 'OK')
            {
                self.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                self.calculateNewSquareVertex(results[0].geometry.location);
                self.drawRects();
            } 
            else
            {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    },
```

I was wondering what's the best way to use google places API in node.js.

Since node is javascript in the server will I be able to use the javascript API in the server? I have seen some people using axios to make requests and building url string, like this:

```
path: '/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&radius=' + radius + '&type=restaurant&key=[YOUR API KEY]',
```

I have also found about this library:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

But I'm not sure about suing a lib, what is the more vanilla, battle tested way to do this?

Can you guys post some of your node.js google places API examples?

Comment: Communication with google works via http requests to a google server. From a technical POV, it doesn't matter whether the browser is making the request or the node engine. The library you've been using is a wrapper around the browser's XMLHttpRequest object, in node it's going to be the [http api](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Which means unless you make the request yourself (by composing the URL and using for instance axios on the server), you must use the node library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) as an http client for this purpose, it makes using the [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#geocoding-lookup) pretty simple.

I've added an example of using the computeOffset function from the [spherical-geometry-js](https://github.com/NotWoods/spherical-geometry-js) module.

Here's an example:

```
const API_KEY = '<your_api_key>'
const axios = require('axios');
const { computeOffset } = require ('spherical-geometry-js');

async function geocode(address) {
    console.log(`Getting result for address ${address}...`);
    const response = await axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodeURI(address)}&key=${API_KEY}`)
    return response.data.results[0];
}

async function testGeocode() {
    const address = "1142-1146 Alta Vista Pl, Brentwood, CA 94513, USA";
    const result = await geocode(address);
    console.log("Latitude:", result.geometry.location.lat);
    console.log("Longitude:", result.geometry.location.lng);
    const { lat, lng } = result.geometry.location;
    // Go 100 meters north
    console.log("Compute offset result:", JSON.stringify(computeOffset({ lat, lng }, 100, 0)));
    console.log("Complete result:", result);
}

testGeocode();
```

Comment: I think I might be using this, only doubt I have is how can I do: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset, in my node.js I don't have access to google object, so I can't do:  new google.maps.LatLng()

Comment: I don't know if you can get the google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset function to work using server side code. But there is a library that can do this: https://github.com/NotWoods/spherical-geometry-js.